# Standard way to store string resources in a Silverlight app

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I'm building a Silverlight 3 application, and I'm wondering what is the best way to store string text for use by the application.

Ideally these strings would be externalized in some sort of XML or independently editable format that isn't binary compiled into my application.

Comment: There is no "standard" was to "externalize" string resources.  I'm guessing that the second sentence is actually more important to you than the first.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to use a `ResourceDictionary` in a Xaml file to achieve this.

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
>
    <sys:String x:Key="hello">Hello</sys:String>
    <sys:String x:Key="world">World</sys:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Note this file does not have an x:Class.  You would not include it as Content or as a Resource in the app build.  You would instead just include it in the ClientBin folder where the XAP gets stored on the web site.

You would then use `WebClient` `DownloadStringAsync` to download this file and shove the resulting string through `XamlReader` which gets you an instance of `ResourceDictionary` that you can now use to resolve string references.  In fact if you add this dictionary to the App.Resources' merged dictionaries its items can resolved as a static resource.

Comment: ok cool.  Does this give any benefits over just having a raw xml file and parsing that raw xml file?  i.e. - thats pretty much what I'm doing here right?

Comment: @keas: Certainly using your own xml file would be pretty straight forward but you would need to write your own xml processing to convert the Xml to some form of dictionary.  So the main advantage of using Xaml as I have here is that `XamlReader` does all that work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Resources File (.resx) to store strings.

Comment: I don't think this gives me teh rebrandability that I want though right, as resource files get compiled into my .dll, whereas I want this file externalized at runtime.  Thats the key thing: "that isn't binary compiled into my application"

Answer (score 0):

Resource File will be the best place to store such string